# How to find out which operation fired the trigger in MySQL

Tags: mysql, triggers

Are special variables like `TG_OP` `TG_TABLE_NAME` (as in postgresql) available in MySQL, if not then is it possible to know for which operation (INSERT, UPDATE etc) the trigger was fired?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mysql defines different triggers for different operations. For Example there would be a trigger for BEFORE INSERT so you would know that insert operation fired the trigger, or there could be a trigger for AFTER UPDATE so you know update caused the trigger to be fired.

Read the tutorials below for having a detailed look on mysql triggers.

http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-trigger-implementation.aspx

http://blog.cnizz.com/2010/11/12/mysql-trigger-how-to-example-tutorial-and-syntax/